# Which random number generator is used in scikit learn and in R?

Tags: r, python, random-forest, random-generation

I want to generate same random numbers as used in R in my RandomForestRegressor class in scikit learn Python library. So I want to know which random number generator is used in R, and how I can replicate this in RandomForestRegressor.

Comment: [Here](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/set.seed) is the help file for random number generation in R.

Comment: Hardy, In documentation it says R uses "Mersenne-Twister" as default algorithms for this. I want to know what is used in scikit-learn or in python

Comment: That is a little different from what you say in the post. Perhaps you should edit the post to state precisely what you are after.